# When I select one product, its ID will be passed to the javascript code below

Tags: javascript, product

When I select one product, its ID will be passed to the javascript code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nameinput_1").click(function(){
    var id = $('#nameinput_1').val();
    $.post("vfiles/data/ajaxload_buy.php",
    {
      id:id,     
    },

    function(html){
      $("#input_1").val(html);
 });    
  });
});
```

which will then produce the price at input_1

```
<input type="text" name="nameinput_1" id="nameinput_1"> <input type="text" name="input_1" id="input_1"> 

<input type="text" name="nameinput_2" id="nameinput_2"> <input type="text" name="input_2" id="input_2">
```

How can I code nameinput_1 so that it automatically changes when I choose a new product without me rewriting it as nameinput_2  ( ex: i --> i++ ). I don't have good ground in javascript so if possible, please help me calculate the sum of input_1 and input_2. Then assign the sum to a new input value.

file ajaxload_buy.php

```
$ID= $_POST['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produce WHERE ID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($ID)."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql)
or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['price'];
```

**I fix this:
I write this so that you have the right not**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".nameinput").click(function() {
        var input = this.name.replace('name', '');
        $.post("vfiles/data/ajaxload_buy.php", {id: this.value}, function(html) {
            $("#" + input).val(html);

             $(this).next().val(html);
             var sum = 0;
                $(".price").each(function() {
                        sum += parseFloat($(this).html());
                });
 **$("#export").val(sum);**

        });
    });
    });
```

How can I export these data in a new input

```
    var sum = 0;
                    $(".price").each(function() {
                            sum += parseFloat($(this).html());
                    });
**$("#export").val(sum);**
```

I do not understand the value (sum) export = NaN

problem is solved

```
var sum = 0;
            $(".price").each(function() {
                    sum += Number(this.value);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some suggestions:

First, use class instead of id so you don't need to duplicate your code. Do something like $(".getprice") instead of $("#nameinput_1") and use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the input element you need:

```
<input type="text" class="getprice" name="nameinput_1" id="nameinput_1"> <input type="text" name="input_1" id="input_1"> 

<input type="text" class="getprice" name="nameinput_2" id="nameinput_2"> <input type="text" name="input_2" id="input_2">
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.post("vfiles/data/ajaxload_buy.php",
    {
      id:id,     
    },

    function(html){
      $(this).next().val(html);
 });    
  });
});
```

Second, if you are sure you have only two things to add up then it's easy to implement based on what you have done. But I still suggest you use a class. Let's say 'price' then the html would be:

```
<input type="text" class="getprice" name="nameinput_1" id="nameinput_1"> <input type="text" name="input_1" class="price" id="input_1">

<input type="text" class="getprice" name="nameinput_2" id="nameinput_2"> <input type="text" name="input_2" class="price" id="input_2">
```

Then you can use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to do something like this when you need to sum prices up:

```
    var sum = 0;
    $(".price").each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).html());
    });
```

Well if you know the id of the new input then it's as simple as $("#id_of_the_input").val(sum);

Comment: I don't have good ground in javascript. complete code javascript so How? you can not help me? thanks so much

Comment: you help me see my edit above does wrong place. thanks so much

Comment: I do not understand the value (sum) export = NaN